# jQuery Buttons - Hide/Unhide Elements or Create & Destroy Dynamic Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener, getelementbyid

I'm building a simple battle game that allows a user to pick 2 characters, have them fight, then proceed to 2 more rounds against other characters.

I have different buttons with unique ids built into my HTML for the stages in the game, for example "PROCEED TO BATTLE", "FIGHT", and "NEXT ENEMY", and as the script progresses my jQuery changes their class assignments to `"hide"` or `"show"` them as needed.

My issue is this: in a new round, when I return to my Battle function, (part of which will hide my NEXT ENEMY button and show my FIGHT button again) and assign a listener for the `click` that affects the HP/DP stats, that operation begins to compound and behave as though hitting my button is firing ever-accumulating listeners. I'm pretty sure this is the case, but verification is appreciated.

So my question is about best practices: **Instead of hiding/unhiding** my button elements depending on the game stage, am I better off defining those elements in my Javascript as variables and creating/destroying them, hopefully along with the event listeners tied to them so that once I return I have a fresh instance of dynamic HTML button and jQuery listener?

I might be missing the key terminology to properly find this solution on my own, so any input helps!

Example:

Let's say I put this in my HTML (even though it seems probably bad practice):

```
<div class="row bottom_aux" id="bottom_aux">
      <a class="btn btn-light hide" id="progress_button">PROGRESS BUTTON</a>
      <a class="btn btn-light hide" id="battle_button">BATTLE BUTTON</a>
      <a class="btn btn-light hide" id="next_battle_button">NEXT BATTLE</a>
</div>
```

with the `hide` class setting `visibility` to `none` or `display` to `hidden`, I've experimented with both. Then in my jQuery I'll bring my button up with `$(".battle_button").toggleClass(show)` or `$(".battle_button").addClass(show)`, but I won't get into the CSS tweaks I made to get it to appear and disappear, I'm just interested in how it affects listener behavior.

Then I unhide the `next_battle_button`, then assign my listener to it for the action I'm setting up.

CONTRAST WITH:

Set my buttons as variables in the javascript:

```
var $battle_button = "<a class='btn btn-light' id='battle_button'>BATTLE BUTTON</a>"
var $next_battle = "<a class='btn btn-light' id='next_battle_button'>NEXT BATTLE</a>"
```

then as I enter that stage I then:

```
$("#battle_button").remove(); // REMOVE BATTLE BUTTON
$("#bottom_aux").html($next_battle); // ADD NEXT FOE BUTTON
$("#next_battle_button").on("click", function() {
       game.nextFoe();
});
```

Hope that illustration helps!

Comment: Hi, your question is quite interesting, but could you please add some code? to make it easier for people to help and get the issue you have faster.

Comment: Sure thing! Lemme see if I can convey this without too much markup . . .

Comment: Are you sure you're not assigning the listener multiple times by accident? For example, you may be calling a function which has `$("#next_battle_button").on(...)` in it

Comment: In regards to best practice; if those buttons are always there (even though you're showing/hiding), it is fine to have them as static html with an id, then attaching listeners with JS

Comment: Thanks Rylee, I do think that's what was happening, I was having difficulty keeping track of my listeners while I hopped through my function calls. I did go back and implement a create/destroy in parent div strategy with jQuery, and it's working well now.